# How to explode and keep white space in strings?

Tags: php, arrays, delimiter, explode, substring

I have a series of country names like:

> United Kingdom Spain Russia Saudi Arabia

The thing is if I do:

```
$stateList = explode('&nbsp;', $stateList);
```

That will result in:

```
United KingdomSpainRussiaSaudi Arabia
```

**UPDATE**

This is what I am doing aftwards:

```
foreach($stateList as $state) { echo $state;
```

But the result is as per above

Comment: explode() won't result in a string, it will result in an array.... what are you doing to that array subsequently?

Comment: @MarkBaker yes I know, I'm then doing                `foreach($stateList as $state) {
                echo $state;` but the result is as per above in the question and that's not right

Comment: Then echo something like a new line (`<br />` for html output) after each element to separate them (`echo $state, '<br />';`)

Comment: Do you know the difference between explode and implode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to differentiate between spaces within country names and spaces as country delimiters.

You could modify your input array and use explode():

```
$state_list='United Kingdom,Spain,Russia,Saudi Arabia';

foreach(explode(',',$state_list) as $state){
    echo $state,"<br>";
}
```

Comment: it doens't but i can make it have it actually, let me try this out

Comment: nope i don't need to, yours should do i think, give a sec, trying it out

Comment: exactly, that was i was planning to do actually

Comment: not yet, still working on it. I cam accept it as it does answer my question tho

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly right, but maybe not what you expect. You have to decide how you want them displayed and add code to do that. For example:

```
foreach($stateList as $state) { 
  echo '<p>' . $state . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: will not this do <p>United</p><p>Kingdom</p>?

Comment: That is just an example, you can replace it with any character/code you like. If you want new line you use `<br>`, if you want to use it in a table you use `<td></td>` and so on.

Comment: Your output code shows spaces already for the two worded countries. So the question seems to be about how to separate the country names because now they are joined.